# Hash code for a wrapper class with a single field

Tags: c#, hash, wrapper, hashcode

I have a wrapper class that will only have a single field and I want to override the GetHashCode method for the wrapper class.

I have written Hash Code algorithms in situations where there are multiple fields (i.e. using xor, shift-and-wrap, etc.) but this is the first time I've ever only had a single field to work with.

1) Should a wrapper and its field return the same hash code? My initial thought is no, it just doesn't feel right that we would knowingly design a class that generates the same hash as another class.

2) If not, would taking the field's hashcode and adding 1 to it suffice or is there a better way to calculate the new hashcode? The field class itself has a good algorithm for generating its hash codes.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "especially because the equals method between the two classes will be the same" - why? It seems you don't want them to be equal, so why not add a type check into it?

Comment: S_F, you are right. There is a type check so the equals returns false. Not sure why I added that bit. I was focused more on the hash code generation than the equals method.

Comment: If I remember correctly, both Hashtable and Dictionary use GetHashCode as well as Equals when looking for a given key etc., so if your implementation of the latter distincts between and instance of your wrapper class and its field, it should be fine as it is. Unless of course you need hash codes for your own algorithms, then the problem is still there.

Comment: S_F, you remember correctly. They use the hash code to find the right 'bucket' and then use the equals to handle collisions. There should be no issue with using Dictionary between the two of them. Something just doesn't sit right with me about having two different classes that generate the exact same hash codes. Maybe I am over thinking things (I tend to do that).

Comment: Yes, you are overthinking things. First, you only need to override `GetHashCode()` (and `Equals()`...they should be done together) if you want to customize equality checks for the type. If you _do_ need to do that, then the implementation should be done based on the type itself, without regard for other types. And returning the `GetHashCode()` value for the single field is perfectly appropriate. Anyway, you can never guarantee that two different instances of two different types won't return identical hash codes, any more than you could for two instances of the same type (except `int`, etc.)

Comment: @PeterDuniho I did some addition research and I agree with you about there being no real need to ensure that the two types return different hashcodes. If you want to throw it into an answer I will accept it (I don't like leaving questions unanswered).

Comment: Okay...done. I think it would've been fine if you'd wanted to just add an answer yourself. But I appreciate the opportunity to answer "long form", to try to explain things in more detail. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Just wanted to give credit where credit is due. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're likely aware, you should override `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` when you want to customize the default equality behavior for the type, as used in various contexts but including hash-table based data structures like `HashSet<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

There are some general rules to follow when doing this (most important being that if two instances your type are equal, they must have the same hash code value), but none of those rules involve worrying about whether a hash value may coincide with the value of an instance of some other type. Indeed, it's not even *necessarily* a problem if a hash value coincides with the value of an instance of the *same* type. Since `GetHashCode()` returns a 32-bit integer, only types that have no more than than 2^32 possible values could even guarantee unique hash values for instances of the same type (e.g. `int`, `short`, `bool`, etc.).

For example, for any given `long` value (64-bit integer), there are 2^32-1 *other* `long` values with the same hash code.

Which is a long way of saying…the simple implementation of just returning as your own type's value for its `GetHashCode()` method, the value that your single field's `GetHashCode()` method returns, is a perfectly acceptable and useful way to implement your `GetHashCode()` method.

It's true that if for some reason you had an instance of the contained object's type and an instance of your own object's type in the same data structure, that there would be a collision (i.e. the two different instances having the same hash code value). But since collisions happen anyway when dealing with hash codes, that's not a problem.